# Mongoengine insert function failed

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a problem about insert function. If i have a array of objects to insert[bad,good,good]. if the first object is bad, and object insert action will fail, then the rest of the objects will never hit the database even the object is good.

How can i deal with it ?

Comment: Could you post the code that is failing, along with the error output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate the model instances before saving to ensure they are valid eg:

```
valid_docs = [d for d in docs if d.validate()]
```

Or pass in the `continue_on_error=True` as a `write_options` eg:

```
Doc.objects.insert(docs, write_options={"continue_on_error": True})
```